# Make button on opposite side of tkinter GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

When I put in my code for this name picker, the gui opens and the two buttons are on top of each other. I understand why this is happening but I do not know how to move it.

This is what it looks like

[image: This is what it looks like]

This is what I want it to look like

[image: is what I want it to look like]

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
import random

names =['Sledge','Thatcher','Ash','Thermite','Twitch','Montagne','Glaz','Fuze','Blitz','IQ','Buck','Blackbeard','Capitão','Hibana']
name = ["Smoke","Mute","Castle","Pulse","Doc","Rook","Kapkan","Tachanka","Jäger","Bandit","Frost","Valkyrie","Caveira","Echo"]

def pickName():
    nameLabel.configure(text=random.choice(names))
def pickName1():
    nameLabel.configure(text=random.choice(name))

root = tkinter.Tk()

root.title("Operator Picker")

root.geometry("400x100")

nameLabel = tkinter.Label(root, text="", font=('Helvetica', 32))
nameLabel.pack()
Grid()

pickButton1 = tkinter.Button(text="Pick Attack", command=pickName)
pickButton1.pack()
pickButton1.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE,height=100, width= 100)
pickButton2 = tkinter.Button(text="Pick Defend", command=pickName1)
pickButton2.pack()
pickButton2.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE,height=100, width= 100)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to pack and place your buttons, you can just pack them. If you want them on opposite sides, try this

```
pickButton1 = tkinter.Button(root, text="Pick Attack", command=pickName, height=100, width=100)
pickButton1.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)
pickButton2 = tkinter.Button(root, text="Pick Defend", command=pickName1, height=100, width=100)
pickButton2.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT)
```

Edit:
When you define the width and height of an object containing text, it is measured in lines and characters instead of pixels, if you want those exact sizes, you need to add frames

```
f1 = tkinter.Frame(root, height=100, width=100) #defines frame size in pixels
f1.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT) #packs on the left
f1.pack_propagate(0) #tells frame not to let children control size
pickButton1 = tkinter.Button(f1, command=pickName, text="Pick Attack")
pickButton1.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1) #takes up all available space

f2 = tkinter.Frame(root, height=100, width=100)
f2.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT)
f2.pack_propagate(0)
pickButton2 = tkinter.Button(f2, command=pickName1, text="Pick Defend")
pickButton2.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)
```

Comment: That's what it looks like using your exact code, the attack takes up too much of the right

Comment: by the way, if i switch attack and defend for right and left, the first image doesnt change

Comment: Updated now @AidanChristopher

Comment: Perfect you rock